# Tomar datos de retorno de un procedimiento almacenado con laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Necesito su ayuda tengo un procedimiento almacenado donde retorna un número

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE factura_grabar(IN numero int,IN serie varchar(7),IN customer_id int, OUT num_fac integer)
BEGIN
    select d.number+1 into num_fac from documents d where d.module='Ventas' and d.serie=serie;
  
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

desde un gestor de base de datos funciona bien, ahora lo quiero llamar desde laravel y al querer tomar el valor de retorno no obtengo nada no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien

```html
public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'client_id' => 'required',
            ],
            [
                'client_id.required' => 'El cliente es requerido.',
            ]
        );
        if (!$validation->fails()) {

            DB::transaction(function() use($request)
            {
                try{
                    $input = $request->all();
                    DB::select("call factura_grabar(1,'001-100',5,@fac)");
                    $results = DB::select('select @fac as num_factu');
                    if ($results) {
                        return $this->insertOk($results);
                    } else {
                        return $this->insertErr(null);
                    }

                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return $this->insertErr(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
                }
            });

        } else {
            return $this->insertErrCustom($validation->messages(), 'Datos inválidos');
        }
    }

}
```

al llamar a este método desde postman no me retorna nada, queda en blanco, no se si estoy haciendo bien el proceso.
Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar un par de cosas:

1. En lugar de ejecutar la sentencia de llamada a tu procedimiento con `DB:select`, utiliza `DB::statement`.
2. Para inspeccionar el resultado de la ejecución de tus querys, sitúa antes de tu DB::enableQueryLog(); y justo después DB::getQueryLog() para obtener el valor. Si no tienes posibilidad de inspeccionar el valor de las variables paso a paso, esto lo escribirá en tu fichero log:

```
try{
    $input = $request->all();
    DB::enableQueryLog(); //A partir de aquí se guardará el resultado de tus querys
    DB::select("call factura_grabar(1,'001-100',5,@fac)");
    $results = DB::select('select @fac as num_factu');
    $resultadoQuery = DB::getQueryLog(); //Esto almacena esos resultados en una variable
    Log::info($resultadoQuery); //Se imprime en el log
    if ($results) {
        return $this->insertOk($results);
    } else {
        return $this->insertErr(null);
    }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::info($e); //Si se produce una excepción, también quedará registrada.
    return $this->insertErr(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```